# static build on multi language web gives unknown filter ":en" yarn

Tags: node.js, pug, yarnpkg

I am making web on pug, node.js and yarn. I can run site locally, but can't make a static build.

My console log:

```
yarn build:static

success Already up-to-date.
$ rimraf static/assets
$ cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --config ./build/prod.webpack.config.js
 10% building 1/2 modules 1 active ...s/Yuriys Web source/src/scripts/main.jsBrowserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `yarn upgrade caniuse-lite browserslist`
Hash: d386d8be808a01f7bf84                                                                     
Version: webpack 4.27.1
Time: 2295ms
Built at: 03/26/2022 5:51:35 PM
                Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    main.469c995c.css   33.5 KiB       0  [emitted]  main
main.469c995c.css.map   40.7 KiB       0  [emitted]  main
     main.469c995c.js   88.8 KiB       0  [emitted]  main
 main.469c995c.js.map    438 KiB       0  [emitted]  main
        manifest.json  218 bytes          [emitted]  
Entrypoint main = main.469c995c.css main.469c995c.js main.469c995c.css.map main.469c995c.js.map
[2] multi ./src/scripts/main.js 28 bytes {0} [built]
[3] ./src/styles/main.scss 39 bytes {0} [built]
[4] ./src/scripts/main.js + 2 modules 1.42 KiB {0} [built]
    | ./src/scripts/main.js 92 bytes [built]
    | ./src/scripts/i18n.js 689 bytes [built]
    | ./src/scripts/awakeness.js 654 bytes [built]
    + 3 hidden modules
Child mini-css-extract-plugin ../Yuriys Web source/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!../Yuriys Web source/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!../Yuriys Web source/src/styles/main.scss:
    Entrypoint mini-css-extract-plugin = *
    [0] ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/styles/main.scss 33.8 KiB {0} [built]
        + 1 hidden module
(node:39801) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: /Users/Yuriy/Downloads/Yuriys Web source/src/pages/partials/header.pug:9:5

unknown filter ":en"
    at makeError (/Users/Yuriy/Downloads/Yuriys Web source/node_modules/pug-error/index.js:32:13)
    at filterWithFallback (/Users/Yuriy/Downloads/Yuriys Web source/node_modules/pug-filters/lib/handle-filters.js:47:17)
    at walk.includeDependencies (/Users/Yuriy/Downloads/Yuriys Web source/node_modules/pug-filters/lib/handle-filters.js:20:18)
    at walkAST (/Users/Yuriy/Downloads/Yuriys Web source/node_modules/pug-walk/index.js:23:18)
    at /Users/Yuriy/Downloads/Yuriys Web source/node_modules/pug-walk/index.js:104:20
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at walkAndMergeNodes (/Users/Yuriy/Downloads/Yuriys Web source/node_modules/pug-walk/index.js:103:18)
    at walkAST (/Users/Yuriy/Downloads/Yuriys Web source/node_modules/pug-walk/index.js:37:19)
    at walkAST (/Users/Yuriy/Downloads/Yuriys Web source/node_modules/pug-walk/index.js:48:21)
    at /Users/Yuriy/Downloads/Yuriys Web source/node_modules/pug-walk/index.js:104:20
(node:39801) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:39801) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
✨  Done in 12.62s.
```

Is it an issue with the config? Or can I even build a static web for GitHub pages?

Comment: My config.js

    const path = require('path');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const CountryLanguage = require('country-language');

const localesForLanguage = language =>
  CountryLanguage.getLanguageMsLocales(language).map(
    ({ langCultureName }) => langCultureName
  );

....

  // Translation settings.
  i18n: {
    localeCookie: '_vc_locale',
    defaultLanguage: 'en',
    defaultCountry: 'EN',
    defaultLocale: 'en-US',
    pugFilters: ['en', 'zh'],
    locales: [...localesForLanguage('en'), ...localesForLanguage('zh')],
  },

Comment: make sure to provide the context files for your question that produces the issue